# Is it possible for nuxt to determine what page is using the /slug path?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a post page and a category page in my project as well as the usual internal pages.

Right now I have the following structure in the pages folder:

- pages/category/_id.vue - I send a request for a category
- pages/post/_id.vue - send request for post
- pages/page/_id.vue - send request for page.

The api for the project is written in laravel (don't know if it matters).

I want nuxt to know which request to send, to fetch category or post, and then choose desired template to display category or post. If there is no category or post, then make redirect to the page 404. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The API provider doesn't matter in this case. Only the logic within Vue/Nuxt page template lifecycle.

Every page template so category / post / page with provided **id** can use different endpoint to fetch the data from API.
Which Nuxt? 2 or 3?

In Nuxt 2 You should use asyncData of specific page template ex: **post**:

```js
async asyncData ({ store, $axios, params, error }) {
  return $axios.get(`${apiEndpoint}/posts`, {
    params: {
      id: params.id
    }
  }).then(item => {
    if (item.data.length === 0) throw({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
    return { item: item.data[0] }
  }).catch(e => {
    error(e)
  })
}
```

If You want to force 404:

```js
try {
 
} catch (err) {
  if (err.response.status === 404) {
    return this.$nuxt.error({ statusCode: 404, message: err.message })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I am using nuxt 2.

Usually we tell nuxt which template to use, depending on that we send a request to get what we need (to get a category or a post). I want to do it the other way around. So that by /slug nuxt itself would understand which template to open to get the post or category.

Comment: @Mojyo alright, I think I see the case. So You want to have the slug dynamic ? 
 So You can use ** route** in asyncData and compare the name of ex: route.name === "post"

Comment: If you move around the site in this way, it might work. But if you refresh the page, nuxt will not understand what parameter we have in the search bar. It will see it, but will not understand what it is 

Comment: Yes, that's true, it'll be  better to use here the **fetch()** https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#fetching-data . Acts as asyncData but can control if it's running on server on not and have access to **this** context

Comment: Unfortunately, whatever we use, asyncData or fetch, nuxt will still not know which template to use when the page is updated. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Mojyo hard to solve it in theory but had similar issue. Then another option is to use  https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#listening-to-query-string-changes but listen for $route **name** change and call $fetch afterwards